# does slave-skip-errors avoid remove errors from the logs

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

We have a third party application that is using a master.slave/master.slave config
and we are experiencing a lot of issues with it

issues like 
mysql process crshing
replication stopping 
timeout connection with the replication user
etc...

its my.cnf file contains slave-skip-errors=126,1053,1105,1129,1158,1159,1160,1161

I'm trying to figure out if when you add any error number to this parameter if this error will appear in the logs and mysql will bypass it
or 
if they will not appear in the logs but mysql will still bypass it

Thank you
Regards

Philippe Courtois

Answer (score 1):

My experience with slave-skip-errors is that errors are skipped silently. I wish I could enable logging but I cannot see how.